HippoMocks: mocking boost::chrono::steady_clock::now
I have some code:
boost::system::error_code clock_error;
const boost::chrono::steady_clock::time_point START = 
boost::chrono::steady_clock::now(clock_error);

and I want to mock the now() function so my test code contains this:
boost::chrono::steady_clock::time_point start(boost::chrono::seconds(0));
boost::system::system_error clock_error(1, BOOST_CHRONO_SYSTEM_CATEGORY, "foo");
mocks.ExpectCallFuncOverload( (boost::chrono::steady_clock::time_point (boost::chrono::steady_clock::*) (boost::system::error_code& clock_error))
                                        &boost::chrono::steady_clock::now)    
                    .With(Out(clock_error))
                    .Return(start);

but this doesn't compile. I get this error:

error: no matches converting function ‘now’ to type
‘boost::chrono::steady_clock::time_point (class
boost::chrono::steady_clock::)(class boost::system::error_code&) {aka
class boost::chrono::time_pointboost::chrono::steady_clock (class
boost::chrono::steady_clock::)(class boost::system::error_code&)}’
mocks.ExpectCallFuncOverload(
In file included from ...
note: candidates are: static boost::chrono::steady_clock::time_point
boost::chrono::steady_clock::now(boost::system::error_code&)
   static BOOST_CHRONO_INLINE time_point  now(system::error_code & ec);

                                          ^

../../../KACotsCode/boost/boost/chrono/system_clocks.hpp:162:46: note:
static boost::chrono::steady_clock::time_point
boost::chrono::steady_clock::now()
static BOOST_CHRONO_INLINE time_point  now() BOOST_NOEXCEPT;
                                          ^


Can anybody spot the problem?

Try replacing (boost::chrono::steady_clock::*) with *? It's a static function anyways, not a member function. Also, please don't mock the clock? Instead, you can use C++ as intended and provide your own chrono-compliant clock type in test builds. But take this with a grain of salt, I've just never understood the appeal of mocking. Instead, I just have decoupled units to test. And use static type composition for integration-type tests.

Here's the Clock concept from the standard library for reference

Changing (boost::chrono::steady_clock::) to just () made no difference.

I looked at HippoMocks. That stuff is very high-tech. I would probably not trust it for production code, since it is very intrusive and completely undocumented¹
However, it does do some impressive stuff on GCC and - judging from the code - MSVC:
Live On Compiler Explorer
#define BOOST_CHRONO_HEADER_ONLY
#include "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dascandy/hippomocks/master/HippoMocks/hippomocks.h"
#include <boost/chrono.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace chrono = boost::chrono;
using Clock      = chrono::steady_clock;

int main() {
    MockRepository mocks;

    boost::system::error_code clock_error = make_error_code(boost::system::errc::file_exists);

    mocks
        .ExpectCallFunc(Clock::now) //
        .With(Out(clock_error))     //
        .Return(Clock::time_point::max());
    auto START = Clock::now(clock_error);

    std::cout                            //
        << clock_error.message() << ": " //
        << std::hex << START.time_since_epoch().count() << std::endl;
}

Prints the expectable
File exists: 7fffffffffffffff

BONUS: Time Traveler Edition
Going back to 2015 (Boost 1.59 August 13th and GCC 4.8.5 June 23rd):
Live On Compiler Explorer²
#define BOOST_CHRONO_HEADER_ONLY
#include "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dascandy/hippomocks/master/HippoMocks/hippomocks.h"
#include <boost/chrono.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace chrono = boost::chrono;
using Clock      = chrono::steady_clock;

int main() {
    std::cout << "Boost version: " << BOOST_VERSION << std::endl;
    std::cout << "GCC version: " << __VERSION__ << std::endl;
    MockRepository mocks;

    boost::system::error_code clock_error = make_error_code(boost::system::errc::file_exists);

    mocks
        .ExpectCallFunc(static_cast<Clock::time_point (&)(boost::system::error_code&)>(Clock::now)) //
        .With(Out(clock_error))                                                                     //
        .Return(Clock::time_point::max());
    auto START = Clock::now(clock_error);

    std::cout                            //
        << clock_error.message() << ": " //
        << std::hex << START.time_since_epoch().count() << std::endl;
}

As you correctly surmised you have to explicitly coerce the overloaded function type. More importantly, HippoMocks doesn't like when you pass the function pointer here, so be sure to case to a function reference: static_cast<Clock::time_point (&)(boost::system::error_code&)>(Clock::now)
Proof of the pudding:
Boost version: 105900
GCC version: 4.8.5
File exists: 7fffffffffffffff



¹ the devs believing that somehow "unfortunately, concise documents restrict access and hinder progress for some developers" [sic]
² Compiler Explorer cannot execute the code because Boost System only became header-only in Boost 1.69.0

I don't know how this compiled for you. now() is an overloaded function and so hippomocks requires you call ExpectCallFuncOverload not ExpectCallFunc. Perhaps I have an old version of hippomocks? This is a legacy system and has old everything. GCC version 4.8.5 and boost version 1.59. I don't have the option to change.

Updated with a time-traveler's edition. Also: whenever you hear "we don't have the option to change" I think "you don't have the luxury to stay behind". It's just bad management. But, we've all been there.

Thanks. This now works with either    mocks.ExpectCallFuncOverload(         (boost::chrono::steady_clock::time_point (&) (boost::system::error_code& clock_error))                                         boost::chrono::steady_clock::now) or mocks.ExpectCallFunc(static_cast<Clock::time_point (&)(boost::system::error_code&)>(Clock::now))
